# How to show the auto product list related to that category When I write category name in a search bar using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show product list related to category. When i write category name inside search bar product list should be shown how to do this ? please help me thanks.

I want to show product list like this, please see image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP1CS.png

This is my search bar please see
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHPOC.png

**Controller**

```
              public function searchproduct(Request $request)
               {
             $query = $request->input('search');
             $productcate = DB::table('products')
            ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'products.cate_id')
            ->where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
             ->orwhere('product_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
             ->orwhere('cate_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
             ->get();

         return view('front_end.products', compact('productcate '));
           }
```

**html view**

```
         <form class="search__form" action="{{route('search.action')}}" method="post" >
         @csrf
        <input class="search__input" name="search" placeholder="Search over 10,000 products" aria-
        label="Site search" type="text" autocomplete="off">
        <button class="search__button" type="submit">
       <svg width="20px" height="20px">
        <use xlink:href="{{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#search-20')}}"></use>
        </svg>
       </button>
       <div class="search__border"></div>
       <div class="product__serach__list">
       <!-- product list will be shown inside this div  -->
       <div id="searchresult" style="background:#fff;border:1px solid #d5d5d5;position: 
        absolute;top: 
       40px;right:0;min-width:100%; display:none;">
        // product list show //
        <span>Search</span>
       </div>
         </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is about so please elaborate.
is the problem with how to display the data recieved from laravel in the blade template? or is it that you want help with the html tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [HTML5 datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) function is what you are looking for.

> The HTML `<datalist>` element contains a set of `<option>` elements that represent the permissible or recommended options available to choose from within other controls.

So if your search area was looking for different types of browsers:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You'll need to supply the data from your server side (or hard code on the html page like I did in this answer), but when a user writes a few letters of a browser name inside search bar, the product list should be shown, as you requested.

Comment: Actully I have product table just i want to show product list  under the search bar  when  i write category name or product name  auto product list should be shown thanks

Comment: This solution will do that.  Or, you can use javascript to highlight, but this is a really simple way to show your products.

Comment: yeah can you guide me how to do this thanks because  i am begineer

Comment: Guidance for using the HTML5 `<datalist>` is exactly what I provided in the answer.  That is easy.  If you want to use a javascript solution, you'll need to do some research / review some tutorials.  Teaching JS and understanding how you wish to implement this is way beyond the scope of what I can answer in a simple answer / comment.